# Remove comma to separate groups of thousands of axis labels in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I took this redraw function from http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434 and I would like to adapt it.

How to remove the comma separator for the groups of thousands? in the code console.log(self.x.ticks(10).map(self.x.tickFormat(2, ".1"))) works and yields numbers in this format: [ "0", "1000", "2000",.. ], which is what I want. When I put it in .data() as in the code I get [ "0", "1,000", "2,000",.. ].
I am using a zoom so i cannot hardcode the labels.

The main part of the code should be:

```
    fx = self.x.tickFormat(10),
    //fx = self.x.tickFormat(d3.format("f2")),    //does not work
    fy = self.y.tickFormat(10);

    // Regenerate x-ticks…
    var gx = self.vis.selectAll("g.x")
            .data(self.x.ticks(10).map(self.x.tickFormat(2, ".1")), String)
            .attr("transform", tx);

    console.log(self.x.ticks(10).map(self.x.tickFormat(2, ".1")))


    gx.select("text")
            .text(fx);
```

The whole redraw function:

```
SimpSimpleGraph.prototype.redraw = function() {
var self = this;
return function() {
    var tx = function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + self.x(d) + ",0)"; 
    },
    ty = function(d) { 
        return "translate(0," + self.y(d) + ")";
    },
    stroke = function(d) { 
        return d ? "#ccc" : "#666"; 
    },
    fx = self.x.tickFormat(10),
    //fx = self.x.tickFormat(d3.format("f2")),    //does not work
    fy = self.y.tickFormat(10);

    // Regenerate x-ticks…
    var gx = self.vis.selectAll("g.x")
            .data(self.x.ticks(10).map(self.x.tickFormat(2, ".1")), String)
            .attr("transform", tx);

    console.log(self.x.ticks(10).map(self.x.tickFormat(2, ".1")))


    gx.select("text")
            .text(fx);

    var gxe = gx.enter().insert("g", "a")
            .attr("class", "x")
            .attr("transform", tx);

    gxe.append("line")
            .attr("stroke", stroke)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("y2", self.height);

    gxe.append("text")
            .attr("class", "axis label")
            .attr("y", self.height)
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(fx) 
            .style("cursor", "ew-resize")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("font-weight", "bold");})
            .on("mouseout",    function(d) { d3.select(this).style("font-weight", "normal");})
            .on("mousedown.drag",    self.xaxis_drag())
            .on("touchstart.drag", self.xaxis_drag());

    gx.exit().remove();

    // Regenerate y-ticks…
    var gy = self.vis.selectAll("g.y")
            .data(self.y.ticks(10), String)
            .attr("transform", ty);

    gy.select("text")
            .text(fy);

    var gye = gy.enter().insert("g", "a")
            .attr("class", "y")
            .attr("transform", ty)
            .attr("background-fill", "#FFEEB6");

    gye.append("line")
            .attr("stroke", stroke)
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("x2", self.width);

    gye.append("text")
            .attr("class", "axis label")
            .attr("x", -3)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text(fy)
            .style("cursor", "ns-resize")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) { d3.select(this).style("font-weight", "bold");})
            .on("mouseout",    function(d) { d3.select(this).style("font-weight", "normal");})
            .on("mousedown.drag",    self.yaxis_drag())
            .on("touchstart.drag", self.yaxis_drag());

    gy.exit().remove();
    //This zoom is call after the plot has loaded
    self.plot.call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(self.x).y(self.y).on("zoom", self.redraw()));

    self.update();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as changing the way d3 outputs numbers, I haven't the foggiest clue.  But you can alter these values afterwards using string prototype [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

**Example**

```
var someString = 'The catcher in the rye';  
someString.replace('catcher','captcha'); //"The captcha in the rye"
```

And here is how you apply this to an array.
http://jsfiddle.net/sq2johrv/1/

Comment: Good workaround, I did not think about that. I added the .label class to the labels and used this:
jQuery(".axis.labels").each(function( index ) { 
     var elem = jQuery(this);
     elem.text(elem.text().replace(",",""))
     });
If anybody knows a solution in D3 it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ticks(myTicksCount, '.f')` instead of .ticks(myTicksCount) to remove the comma to separate groups of thousands.

For details, see the **docs** on

https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_ticks

https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickFormat

https://github.com/d3/d3-format

You can **test** the format specifiers (including your own) on http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e

Comment: Add some description, it would be more useful

Comment: @Billa I've added resources, I don't exactly what description specifically would help here, but I am happy to hear suggestions

Comment: '.0f' made it work for me.